# CSS scroll bar offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a scrollable box and a header. The header is in the absolute top position and the box has an upper padding of the same height as the header, in this way the scrolled content passes below the header. The problem is that the scroll bar also has a portion below the header, as it is not affected by the padding. I would like the scroll bar to start at the end of the header.

```html
<div className={"relative"}>
    <Title className={"text-center fixed inset-x-0 top-0 backdrop-blur-md bg-gray-50/40 py-2 z-50"}>Ultimi aggiornamenti</Title>
    <div className={"scroll-pt-14 overflow-y-auto snap-y overscroll-contain snap-mandatory pt-12 pb-5 h-[60vh] px-3"}>
        <Content></Content> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

[image: The scrollbar is visible under the header]

I tried putting the sliding box down the header. This way the problem disappears: the scroll bar is in the right position. However, the blur effect of the header, which I would like to keep, also disappears.

```html
<div>
    <Title className={"text-center py-2"}>Ultimi aggiornamenti</Title>
    <div className={"overflow-y-auto snap-y overscroll-contain snap-mandatory pb-5 h-[60vh] px-3"}>
        <Content></Content> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of have having the box be scrollable, simply have the entire page scroll. Because the `<Title />` is above the box, the box's own scrollbar will always be below it.

```html
<div className={"relative"}>
    <Title className={"text-center fixed inset-x-0 top-0 backdrop-blur-md bg-gray-50/40 py-2 z-50"}>Ultimi aggiornamenti</Title>
    <div className={"snap-y overscroll-contain snap-mandatory pt-12 pb-5 h-[60vh] px-3"}>
        <Content></Content> 
    </div> 
</div>
```